# chrome set opacity is not consistentanly rendering as expected

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I've spend about a week looking for an answer and trying various different ways of setting the opacity and forcing the various elements to redraw in order to update the full amount.

This renders fully in firefox https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1u7n.png

```js
var hex = document.getElementsByClassName('hex')[0];
hex.classList.add("highlight");
```

```css
.hex {
    float: left;
    margin-right: -29px;
    margin-bottom: -52px;
    height: 104px;
    width: 120px;
}

.highlight {
    opacity:0.50;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
}

.desert {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/zAr9w6T.png");
}

.periplaneta{
    fill : #FF9933;
    stroke : black;
}


a {
    color: inherit;
}

.menu {
    background: #8bc34a;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-item, .menu-open-button {
    background: #e91e63;
    border-radius: 100%;
    width: 25px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-left: -40px;
    position: absolute;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 25px;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform ease-out 200ms;
    transition: transform ease-out 200ms;
}

.menu-open {
    display: none;
}

.menu-item:hover {
    background: white;
    color: #e91e63;
}

.menu-open-button {
    z-index: 2;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.32, 1.275);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 400ms;
    transition-duration: 400ms;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: scale(1.1, 1.1) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    cursor: pointer;
}

.menu-open-button:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.7, 1.7) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: scale(1.7, 1.7) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked + .menu-open-button {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
    transition-timing-function: linear;
    -webkit-transition-duration: 200ms;
    transition-duration: 200ms;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    transform: scale(0.8, 0.8) translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item {
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.935, 0, 0.34, 1.33);
    transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.935, 0, 0.34, 1.33);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(3) {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 180ms;
    transition-duration: 180ms;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-40px, -25px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-40px, -25px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(4) {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 280ms;
    transition-duration: 280ms;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(40px, -25px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(40px, -25px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(5) {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 380ms;
    transition-duration: 380ms;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(40px, 25px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(40px, 25px, 0);
}

.menu-open:checked ~ .menu-item:nth-child(6) {
    -webkit-transition-duration: 480ms;
    transition-duration: 480ms;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-40px, 25px, 0);
    transform: translate3d(-40px, 25px, 0);
}

.rotate{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s linear;
    transition: all 0.5s linear;
}

.rotate.down{
    -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
    transform:rotate(180deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="hex desert"><nav class="menu"><input type="checkbox" href="#" class="menu-open" name="menu-open53" id="menu-open53" disabled=""><label class="menu-open-button" for="menu-open53" style="background: orange;"><i class="fa rotate action-display fa-arrow-right"></i></label><a href="#" class="menu-item" onclick="lockInAction(this,'fa-arrow-right')" style="background: orange;"> <i class="fa fa-arrow-right move-action"></i> </a><a href="#" class="menu-item" onclick="lockInAction(this,'fa-shield')"> <i class="fa fa-shield defence-action"></i> </a><a href="#" class="menu-item" onclick="lockInAction(this,'fa-bug')"> <i class="fa fa-bug recruit-action"></i> </a><a href="#" class="menu-item" onclick="lockInAction(this,'fa-cog')"> <i class="fa fa-cog harvest-action"></i> </a></nav><svg height="100" width="100"><g><circle cx="30" cy="60" r="15" id="inf" class="periplaneta"></circle><text x="25" y="65" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" fill="black">1</text></g><g><polygon points="60,5 40,40 80,40" class="periplaneta"></polygon><text x="55" y="35" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" fill="black">2</text></g><g><rect x="50" y="50" width="40" height="40" class="periplaneta"></rect><text x="60" y="75" font-family="Verdana" font-size="20" fill="black">1</text> </g></svg></div>
```

What is causing this? There are 432 hexes on the page. But i'm only looking to highlight a maximum of 6 of them. Any thoughts/insights would be really appreciated.

Comment: A video of my issue can be seen here   https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz5xmbVsswlGWnlqNXpZRmhPb28/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after spending a week investigating this it looks to be a bug with Chrome.

In place of changing the opacity I opt'd for applying a webfilter to highlight the hexes as a workaround for the bug in chrome.

```
-webkit-filter: brightness(110%);
-webkit-filter: sepia(70%);
-webkit-filter: hue-rotate(-15deg);
```

I hope this helps anyone experiencing the same issue